# equation of a circle ,standard form

Tags: geometry

I am supposed to be finding the equation of a circle that have a center (√5,2√2) and radius of √10 by using the standard form

I already know the distance formula but I could'nt figure out how to solve this given center.

Answer (score -1):

$(x - \sqrt{5})^2 + (y-2\sqrt{2})^2 = 10$